# Executing a function upon webhook calling wordpress

Tags: plugin-development, customization

I assume it is best to have webhooks that run from like say thrivecart, or other processors, execute code from a plugin, so that updates do not overwrite custom coding...

I've never created a plugin before, and just learned how to create a very basic plugin.

So I've done that. My question is, how do I have a webhook execute it on callback?

Say something like S2member does it:

google.com/?s2membersomethingorother=1 (removed the https to keep it from creating a link)

is that the way, then have WP listen for that value, and if it exists, execute that code in the plugin?

But how do I get WP to listen and not quit listening after updates?

Is there a best practice for it?

I need a simple few lines of code to check if the user is valid then upgrade their membership role.
I have the code for S2Member to check it all, but no idea how to get WP to execute it.

Can someone point me to a resource where I can learn that?

I've scoured the API and scripting stuff, but cannot seem to find what I'm looking for.

I'd appreciate any assistance you can offer.

My best,
-Richard

Comment: I forgot about mu-plugins - would it be best to put the code in there? if so, how do I get a hook to execute it?

Comment: I think I got it... I can put any file in the mu-plugins folder... then have it check if $_REQUEST['whateveriwant'] exists, if it does, then execute code. If not, then it is not a call from the webhook... and just do nothing... that is a simple check, and should not bog down the system... I don't think... what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create an extra file for that. 
Simply place something like the following into your themes functions.php file:

```
function grab_my_very_own_webhook(){

    if( ! isset( $_GET['whateveriwant'] ) ){
        return;
    }

    //create your own logic here

}
add_action( 'init', 'grab_my_very_own_webhook' );
```

In case you want to grab some data that is sent by the webhook, you need to catch it and validate it properly. 
There's a plugin that takes that work from you nicely: [WP Webhooks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-webhooks/)

WP Webhooks will catch the data for you and you simply need to write an extension where you handle the data you want to use. They have a [custom plugin template](https://ironikus.com/docs/knowledge-base/create-custom-extension-for-wp-webhooks-pro/) available, which you can use to create your own endpoint to use the validated data.